# no value given for required parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

ACCESS 2013 database and i have 2 table 1 for user and table 2 for books i want to display all books that have been taken by user 1 and already did it i want to ask why there are error in query in visual studio and it works fine in MS-ACCESS 2013 query builder the database are in this link and u will find the query result image and display me no value required for parameter i think i did everything gd.

[Database link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AC25D7A2DC192BDB!13075&authkey=!ADIZowoI9S8xJms&ithint=folder%2CJPG)

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"");
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        try
        {

            string R = "SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Relation WHERE Table1.ID = 1";
            command.CommandText = R;
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ID1.Text = reader["Table1.ID"].ToString();
                    fName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    lName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    ID2.Text = reader["Table2.ID"].ToString();
                    book.Text = reader["Book"].ToString();
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that Table2.Relation should be Table2.ID

Comment: i want to display the result based on table2.Relation becuase its lookup field and related with Table1.ID

Comment: no his child column in Table2 is labeled Relation.   Are you setting your connection string some place where I can't see it?  Not that I need to but you're not setting it in this code.

Comment: the relation is already there between the Table1.id and Table2.Relation

Comment: but how to display the data coming from this query do i need to create new table or i can display it normally ?? book.Text = reader["Book"].ToString(); is it wrong ??

Comment: guys sry i was exhausted from working the code works really fine and the material i will share it with all sorry for not being wake